# Squarespace removes UTM query variables when redirecting from non-www to www

Tags: redirects, url, squarespace

I'm setting up some redirects for a client's blog, pointing the old URLs to their new Squarespace site.

Curiously, I noticed some of URL tracking variables were being stripped out during the redirect.

This URL: `https://olddomain.com/blog/blogpost-title?utm_medium=email&utm_source=campaign_monitor&utm_campaign=bridgit_newsletter&utm_content=sneakpeak_mar0719`

Should have been redirected to: `https://squarespacedomain.com/new-blogpost-slug?utm_medium=email&utm_source=campaign_monitor&utm_campaign=bridgit_newsletter&utm_content=sneakpeak_mar0719`

But instead it was being redirected to: `https://www.squarespacedomain.com/new-blogpost-slug?utm_content=sneakpeak_mar0719`

Only some `utm_` variables were being removed. If I included `?var_a=test&var_b=test`, they would make it through just fine.

The other unanticipated change is that, somewhere in the process, `www.` got added to the URL.

Looking at the trace, there were actually two redirects happening.

[image: results of URL trace]

Armed with this new information, I edited the redirect to point directly to the `www.` version of the squarespace URL. When I did that, it stopped stripping out the `utm_` variables.

**So I have a few questions:**

1. Why would Squarespace want to strip out certain `utm_` query variables?
2. Why would it strip those variables only during a non-www to www redirect?
3. Is this a bug Squarespace should fix, or is there a reason for this behaviour?

Comment: How are these redirects implemented?   Is this code that you put in a *.htaccess* file or is this a "add www" checkbox feature of squarespace?

Comment: The first redirect happens from my server's `.htaccess` file. The second redirect happens on Squarespace's server – there's no way to edit the .htaccess on Squarespace or disable their www redirects as far as I can tell. But as evidenced by the behaviour above, it's clear they're doing more than just redirecting to www.

Answer (score 2):

After having the same issue I reached out to Squarespace support and received the following workarounds:

1. If you use the www version of a link, such as `www.yourlink.com` vs. `yourlink.com`, it will prevent the parameters from being stripped.
2. Another option would be to use `#` instead a `?` when creating the utm tracking.

We implemented #1, and it's been working seamlessly.